# Special linear group as submanifold.

Tags: group-theory, multivariable-calculus, differential-topology, parametric

For the special linear group $SL(2,\mathbb{R}) = \{A \in Mat_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})|\det A = 1\}$, I'm trying to find continuous and differentiable functions $P_k : D_k \rightarrow Mat_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R}), k = 1,2,...$ with open domains $D_k \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, such that $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is the union of the images of $P_1, P_2, ...$

Now I do understand that it makes sense to look separately at matrices with entry $a_{11} = 0$ and those with entry $a_{11} \neq 0$, but once I start to come up with examples, it just doesn't work out. So does anybody have suggestions on how I could tackle this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The matrix exponential can be used to give a nice map from the traceless 2x2 matrices into $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$, which gives a coordinate chart around the identity. You can multiply this map by other elements of $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ to get a local coordinate chart wherever you want.

Answer (score 1):

By Gaussian elimination in the form of the [LDU decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#LDU_decomposition), any $M \in \text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, may be factored either as 
$$
M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
z & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{x}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & y \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x & xy \\
xz & xyz + \frac{1}{x}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
or as
$$
M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
z & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{x}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & y \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 \\ 
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
xy & -x \\
 xyz + \frac{1}{x} & -xz \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

We know the diagonal matrix has the form it does with $x\ne 0$, as $\det M = 1$. Hence, the right hand sides as a function of $(x,y,z)$, $x\ne 0$ completely parameterize $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$.